# How can I set up multiple Continuum servers to share a log file directory on NFS?

Tags: continuum

We have two Continuum server setup in a HA configuration and want to share log data between them using a shared NFS directory. How can we configure the two Continuum servers to both read and write log data to the NFS location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two Continuum services cannot open a file handle to the same log file, as the service locks the file once the first service opens it.
Job logs will fail in this scenario, while the use of NFS for log storage has not been tested. 
We do not know any reason why the logs could not be stored on an NFS share with the caveat that two services cannot write to the same log file.